# How to get table field name from a FormBuildStringControl control

Tags: axapta, x++

I would like to ask how I can take the physical table field Name from  a FormBuildStringControl.

Genarally I could say that I have to loop all string controls of a form.
and find the correcponding Table field Names.

At first I achive to navigate through all controls with the help of the following link. [Loop form fields](http://microsoft-dynamics-ax-erp.blogspot.de/2012/07/iterate-through-all-controls-of-form.html)

The first part works like a charm and I can navigate into form controls without any promlems, but  my Problem is when I would like to find the Table fieldName.

```
     switch(control.handle())
       {  
          case classnum(FormBuildStringControl):  

          FormBuildStringControl   formBuildStrControl =Control FormBuildStringControl;
          str name = formBuildStrControl.name();
          info( formBuildStrControl.name()); // THE CORRECT VALUE  CustTable_CustAccount

          info(fieldId2Name(formBuildStrControl.dataSource(),formStrControl.Datafield()));// THE FALSE VALUE ORDERID

         info(tableId2Name(formBuildStrControl.dataSource()))// false  value SalesLine

         break;
    }
```

I have not the excpected results from the methods fieldId2Name(), and tableId2Name(). the reason is the datadield and the datasource() methods does not return the corrects IDs from the SalesTable and from CustAccount

Have someone any suggestion how I can get out the correct table field Name from a FormBuildStringControl ?

Thanks
Nikos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your value `formStrControl.dataSource()`.

Change that to `formStrControl.dataSourceObject().table()`.

**Something you may find more useful** is `FieldBinding` from `formStringControl.fieldBinding()`, which provides all of the information you'd probably want.

Here's some code that shows what I'm talking about:

```
FormStringControl           fsc;
FieldBinding                fieldBinding;

// Using your current method
fsc = element.control(element.controlId('CustTable_AccountNum'));    
info(strFmt("%1", fieldId2name(fsc.dataSourceObject().table(), fsc.dataField())));

// Using Field Binding
fieldBinding = fsc.fieldBinding();
info(strFmt("%1, %2, %3", fieldBinding.fieldId(), fieldBinding.fieldName(), fieldBinding.tableId()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looks like a desent solution , but  in my method  I do not have this **element** object or at least an object which has the controlId method.   fsc = **element**.control(**element.controlId('CustTable_AccountNum')**);

Comment: Also i would like to say that there is not a method DataSourceObject() for the FormBuildStringControl   object, :(  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/formbuildstringcontrol.aspx , so still cannot take correct  values.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to post my solution for my question which come out from the post of @Alex Kwitny

```
                case classnum(FormBuildStringControl):

                FormStringControl        fsc =  new FormStringControl(control as FormBuildStringControl,_formRun)  ;
                FieldBinding             fieldBinding;

                fieldBinding = fsc.fieldBinding();
                info(strFmt("%1, %2, %3", fieldId2Name(fieldBinding.tableId(),fieldBinding.fieldId()), fieldBinding.fieldName(), tableId2Name( fieldBinding.tableId())));

                 _this.add(fieldBinding.fieldId());

                 break;
```